# searchable Kendo dropdown in not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have Used Kendo drop down list for Employee code 
I want to Provide search functionality in this drop down
but I have used filter option in this drop down but it not working
when I used filter option at that time drop down is open and after open it close at that time 
so I am not able to select or search any thing in this drop down

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
     .Name("PCODE")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
     .DataTextField("PCODE")
     .DataValueField("EmpId")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "kendo-Drop-PCode" })
     .AutoBind(true)
     .Filter("contain")
     .DataSource(source => 
        {
         source.Read(read => 
             read.Action("GetEmployeeList", "Common");
       });
}))
```

Comment: It should be .Filter("contains") not contain

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an open `{` for read...

```
.DataSource(source => 
        {
         source.Read(read => 
             read.Action("GetEmployeeList", "Common");
       });
```

should be..

```
.DataSource(source => 
        {
         source.Read(read => {
             read.Action("GetEmployeeList", "Common");
       });
```

Also, the filter should be `.Filter("contains")` and you may need `.ServerFiltering(true);` set too.  You can also use `.Filter("startswith")` for the filter.

Comment: Why was there a @downvote? At least leave a comment to suggest why?